# Python to .exe with pyinstaller not re sizable problem

Tags: python

I'm currently creating a application in python and used pyinstaller to compress the python file to an .exe file. Is there a way or line of code that i can use to make the .exe window not be re sizable?

Comment: This would depend on which library you're using for the UI. How are you displaying data to the user? Is it a console, or `tkinter`, or some other graphical library?

Comment: Its displayed in the console as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `resizable` method of Tkinter in the original app.

```
from tkinter import Tk, mainloop, TOP 
from tkinter.ttk import Button 
  
# creating tkinter window 
root = Tk() 
  
# creating fixed geometry of the 
# tkinter window with dimensions 150x200 
root.geometry('200x150') 

## fixed size
root.resizable(height=0, width=0)
  
button = Button(root, text = 'TEST') 
button.pack(side = TOP, pady = 5) 
  
mainloop()
```

Zero `height` and `width` parameters in the `root.resizable` simply means its non-resizable.

Comment: This doesn't work sadly, I'll recreate my project in tkinter and use this method. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

for some reason when i compile it with `mainCoreRoot`(just did it instead of root)`.resizeable(False,False)` it makes the window title box more slimmer like the height is decreased when i compile it into .exe with pyinstaller, here is problem:

with nonresizeable
[slim titlebox][1]

with resizeable
[normal titlebox][2]

i dont know why when its compiled that happens..

Edit: btw i am not using geometry
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxsLQ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSTyK.png